# Non-greedy match is still too greedy

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern that needs to capture the shortest matches, but the lazy match isn't working in cases where that pattern is nested. Here's what I mean:

Regex pattern:

```
/{{.*?}}/
```

Example string:

```
{{This}} is {{an example {{sentence}}}}
```

In the above example, I'm expecting to pull `{{This}}` and `{{sentence}}`, as these are the shortest matches, but instead I am getting `{{This}}` and `{{an example {{sentence}}`. Why is the non-greedy match still being so greedy - or rather, where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.` matches any character, that is why you match `{{` followed with any characters but a newline up to the first `}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: `{{[^{]*?}}`
This is using the fact that the '{' character should not appear in the inner strings. It does match what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Cyb3rFly3r , I didn't consider a negative operator. I'm still not 100% sure I understand why this is happening - I thought non greedy would always prioritise the shortest available match - but in effect this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem is that `.*` matches everything. if you want just to match content between `{{` and `}}`, you can try following regex:

```
\{{2}[^\{]*?\}{2}
```

See demo [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nT3yX1/1)